# How to use scroll view? Are there example codes?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I am doing android app. The main activity is a listview. The xml file of the main activity is as following.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TableLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:id="@+id/TableRow01"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="fill" 
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/Button01"
                            android:layout_width="48dp"
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_action_search"
                            android:onClick="search" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="48dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:hint="Employer?date?program?"
                            />
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/taboneviewlist"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" >
                </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

When we click each item in the list view, data_activity appears. The xml file of the each item (data_activity) in the list view is as following.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/employer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

<View 
    android:id="@+id/employer_line"
    android:layout_height="4sp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FF909090"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<!-- Table: Date -->
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_title"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="Time"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</TableRow> </TableLayout>
```

Now the data_activity can not display all the information. The question is how to make the data_activity scroll? Are there any example codes?

Answer (score 0):

Put your top-level view into a `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
        ...
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried this method this morning. But when I clicked each item in the list view, the data_activity did not appear.

Comment: @ChengchengPei how exactly did it not appear? Did it print anything to log?

Comment: It seems the following function does not work. "Something" does not display on the logcat. Codes: ``DataListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.taboneviewlist); 
DataListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);  
mListAdapter = new ListAdapterData(this, data1);
DataListView.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
DataListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
// Log.v("tag", "something")
            }
        });``

Comment: When I put the scollview inside the listview, the item in the list view seem can not be clicked.

Comment: @ChengchengPei `ListView` should be never put into `ScrollView`, see [the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: I put lots of items in a listview, which can be scrolled and clicked. When one item is clicked, data_activity of the item come out. My problem is that the table layout can not display all the infomation. So I tried to use a scroll view to contain the table layout, but when the table layout is contained in the scrollview, the item in the listview cannot be clicked. WHat should I do now?